# asp.net - FileUpload Object Reference Not Set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a FileUpload on azure, and this code really works fine.

```
string filePath = fileASP.FileName;
            string fileType = fileASP.PostedFile.ContentType;

            string[] cut = filePath.Split('.');

            Array.Reverse(cut);

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(store, blobUri, queueUri, tableUri);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.Next(1, 1000);

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(randomNum.ToString() + "." + cut[0]);
            txtID.Text = randomNum.ToString();

            using (fileASP.PostedFile.InputStream) //System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileASP.PostedFile.InputStream);
            }
```

It works perfectly. But this is only for my dummy program. When I transfer it to my application, I always get the error of `Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object`. This is my code for my application:

```
string filePath = dtiFileUpload.FileName;

            string[] cut = filePath.Split('.');

            Array.Reverse(cut);

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(wac.Credentials, wac.BlobUri, wac.QueueUri, wac.TableUri);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum1 = rand.Next(1000, 99999);
            int randomNum2 = rand.Next(1000, 99999);

            string path = "http://cspdemo.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ClearanceDTI-" + randomNum1 + randomNum2 + "." + cut[0];

            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);

            using (dtiFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(dtiFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);
            }
```

The error is on `using (dtiFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)`. I've always known this error, and I know that my FileUpload control dtiFileUpload contains a null value that's why it raises an exception. But what is my error? The code is the same with my dummy program, and I don't know on where I am wrong. I have `<form id="newForm" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">` on my master page. Where can i possibly be wrong?

Comment: `dtiFileUpload` cannot be null, otherwise you would get the exception already on the first line. So i assume that `dtiFileUpload.PostedFile` is null. Maybe you're using `UpdatePanels`. Then use the `AsyncFileUpload` control instead.

Comment: dtiFileUpload has a value. but the program raises it as null. i tried placing a breakpoint on string filePath = dtiFileUpload.FileName; and it returns empty string. what is my error?

Comment: i am not using UpdatePanels.

Comment: You have to handle the upload on the next postback, not on consecutive postbacks. You can use `FileUpload1.HasFile` to check if the upload controls has a file.

Comment: yea, i tried validating it by using HasFile, and it always returns false.

Comment: Please make sure that you are uploading file to fileupload with name dtiFileUpload. It might be possible that you are uploading to different and fetching from different.

Comment: i'm sure it is uploading on the dtiFileUpload control. i really can't debug this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the following locations:

- First line: `dtiFileUpload` cannot be null
- Second line: `filePath` cannot be null

I recommend you debug the method stepping in line by line and you will get the exact location of your problem, otherwise please post the stack trace of the exception and you should have the line number specified in it (make sure the .pdb files are present in the directory from where you are executing your application)

Comment: i tried debugging it line by line, and dtiFileUpload and filePath is null even though i placed a file in it.